# How to avoid of of of in the Appendix title

Tags: prepositions, titles, headline-english

I am writing a book and I am supposed to write a title of an Appendix. The logic would go like this:

> Summary of the models of probability of occurrence

But isn't it clumsy, to use so many of's in a title? Can it be done more elegantly in English?

Thought about this:

> Summary of the occurrence probability models

But I'm not sure if it's correct, especially the "occurrence probability models" part.

Please let me know in your answer if your answer is based on your experience in this area (statistical modelling), or if it's based on knowledge of general English. This is important to me to consider as well, whether, in this area, I can say "occurrence probability models".

Comment: *But isn't it clumsy, to use so many of's in a title?* No. People are reading this for knowledge, not its literary merit.

Comment: Note to commenters: **Do not answer in comments.** Write an answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't like you deleting people's comments!!! There were some useful suggestions!!!!

Comment: Don't you think you'd get more help in Writing SE, or pages dealing with probability or modelling? Either way what extant texts are you comparing this to for clumsiness, or any other quality?

Answer (score 1):

"occurrence probability models" will confuse anybody not in a technical area that uses this term (you can find it by Googling, but it's not the usual terminology in any area I know).

I would suggest

> models for probability of occurence;

"models for" and "models of" are more or less interchangeable in many fields of science, and "models for" avoids the repetition of "of".

Comment: or "Models of Probability Occurrence, a Summary"